# Linux seems to have acquired a lot of *at calls? What is the motivation for these?

Tags: linux, system-calls, relative-path

I've noticed that Linux now has `renameat`, `fstatat`, `openat` and a variety of other calls that allow you to specify paths relative to a file descriptor instead of having them be interpreted relative to the process' current working directory as is normally the case.

Why have these calls been added? There seems to be `at` versions of most system calls that have path name arguments, so there must be a pretty compelling use-case for this. But I can't think what it is.

Comment: The idea behind is to support as longest path as we have memory for. And it's bad idea to have it related to something which is arbitrary.

Comment: I think it can be handy to refer to paths relative to something else than the current dir. And it can also help the kernel: instead of passing long paths, many times, a process can pass shorter, relative ones - the kernel already has some cached data for the fd you pass as parameter.

Comment: I suspect the reason is more compelling than the ones you both list. I suspect it may relate to processes being able to work predictably with a particular directory even if it's renamed.

Comment: @Omnifarious I don't think: renaming files or directories does not cause problems to open handles; Unix knows that since more than 30 years.

Comment: @linuxfan No, it doesn't, and that's the point. If you open the directory, then you can give pathnames that are relative to it that will continue to work even if it's renamed if you use the *`at` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these `*at` routines were introduced as part POSIX. If you dig into the rationale section of the [openat routine](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html), you will find the following paragraph:

> The purpose of the openat() function is to enable opening files in directories other than the current working directory without exposure to race conditions. Any part of the path of a file could be changed in parallel to a call to open(), resulting in unspecified behavior. By opening a file descriptor for the target directory and using the openat() function it can be guaranteed that the opened file is located relative to the desired directory.

In other words, it's a security measure.